# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/content/03/11247403/html/wp-content/themes/kerdowney-2810/t_destinations.php on line 183

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm working on a WordPress site, i keep on getting this warning. i thought it has something to do with my magic fields maybe i named something wrong but its still giving me the same error.

How do i solve this problem.
I have this piece of code on t_destinations.php

```
$ras = getGroupOrder('recommended_accommodation_title' , $ras);
foreach ($ras as $ra) :
  $ras_title = get('recommended_accommodation_title', $ras);
  $ra_link = get('recommended_accommodation_link', $ra);
  $link = !empty($ra_link) ? $ra_link : '#';
```

Comment: `vardump($ras)` -- And pls use curly braces for loops. Its just ridiculous if ppl want to make code as short as possible but in the end its just unreadable ...

Comment: check if something is returned `if( !empty($ras) && is_array($ras) ){foreach...}`

Comment: Did you also use `endforeach;` ?

Comment: @YUNOWORK So you're saying that Python is unreadable? ;)

Comment: @Carsten yes Python is unreadable most of the time ;)